# Trigger BeforeUpdate caused by: System.FinalException: Record is read-only

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

[image][image]

Created one book object in that applying for update trigger on age condition if book type is horror ae should be updates as 21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to update old value through `Trigger.old`, thats why the error is.

> Trigger.old is always read only.

Try to update new value `Trigger.new` instead of `Trigger.old`

Refer [Context Variable Considerations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_context_variables_considerations.htm)